# AS3 Code Structure - Using Base Code

Tags: actionscript-3, architecture, structure, flash, swc

I would like some advice on something. I have many games which all use the same base code, and they extend the base classes overriding anywhere they need their own custom functionality. This is fine, but it has reached a point where it has become unreasonable every time I make a change to the base code, I need to republish every individual game. I would like a solution where I only need to change the base code and publish it itself and the other games will then just use this new published base.

I thought about publishing the base code as a swf and then loading it into the individual game projects, but then I won't be able to extend the classes right? Or about publishing the base code as a swc but then I would still need to publish each individual game with this new swc I think.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions that would help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Runtime Shared Library or implement a continuous integration service that rebuilds on commit to your version control system.

Comment: An interesting question!  You can load in a Runtime Shared Library (.swf) and have it replace classes and display assets, but I've never tried loading in just a base class in an attempt update functionality without re-compiling. Might be worth trying but I doubtful it will work.

Comment: why would you need to republish all your game each time you make a change?

Comment: Can you use Runtime Shared Libraries with pure AS3 projects or does it need to be Flex?

Comment: I need to republish all the games because I need them to include the additions I've made to the base code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not exactly the answer to this question, my resolution to this problem was to automate the build process using ANT. So every game does still need to be compiled and uploaded again, but it is no longer unreasonably time consuming.